# plasma (5) widget for audio streams

Tags: sound, widgets, internet-radio, plasma-5, stream

I am searching for a plasma widget like any media player BUT: for audio streams (ie. radio streams, other public hosted streams). Does anybody know about something like this? Nice to have might be something like a customizable playlist :D

Thanks in advance!